# Array in csv download

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

I'm having an issue export my array correctly to a csv. In my output I'm getting the content in the right columns, but it's displaying the key value as well:

**Array**

```
{"20160828"=>{:min_temp=>5.6, :max_temp=>24.7}}
```

**Output in csv**

```
Date     | Min Temp                 |   Max Temp
20170828 | &quot;{:min_temp=&gt;5.6 |   :max_temp=&gt;24.7
```

**show.csv.erb**

```
<% headers = ['Date', 'Min Temp', 'Max temp'] %>
<%= CSV.generate_line headers %>
<% @results.each do |key,value| %>
<%= CSV.generate_line([key, value.each do |k,v| v end]) %>
<% end %>
```

The above loop works fine in my show.html.erb, so is the issue with csv conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue. See below code change if anyone is interested. To remove the `&quot;` comments I used `.html_safe`.

```
<% headers = ['Date', 'Min Temp', 'Max Temp'] %>
<%= CSV.generate_line headers %>
<% @results.each do |key| %>
<%= CSV.generate_line([key[0], key[1][:min_temp], key[1][:max_temp]]).html_safe %>
<% end %>
```

Someone might have a better solution though.